# Effective collision energy at LHC

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

The proton is not a fundamental particle, so in high energy proton-proton collision we actually collide proton's sub-constituents: quark-quark and (mostly) gluon-gluon. LHC operates now at 13 TeV center of mass energy but the effective collision energy is less than 13TeV since the sub-constituents carry only a fraction (given by the pdf) of this energy. My question is how would it look the distribution of this effective energy? What is the mean collision energy?

Comment: It's a good question, but it may not be quite the one you mean to ask. The different detectors select a different subsets of the events to examine, and for experimental purposes the question you want is *"What is the distribution of parton center-of-momentum energies in accepted events?"*. Even then the answer depends a bit on what trigger is used but you can ask about the least biases data-initiated trigger.

Comment: @dmckee, the question can be answered through theoretical calculations, without having to "cut it down" to what the detectors accept. (Although it'll take considerably more time than what I just devoted in order to write a proper answer.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the final state as can readily by seen by studying the conservation of 4-momentum. Let's consider the simplest case of two particles or two jets in the final state (a $2\to 2$ event as we call it):

$$x_ap_a + x_b p_b = p_1+p_2,$$

where $a$ and $b$ denotes the protons and $1$ and $2$ denotes the final particles, and of course $x$ denotes the fraction of the proton momentum carried by the interacting partons. Then we take the $z$-axis along the beam axis as usual and for each final particles we introduce the transverse energy:

$$E_T^2 = E^2-p_z^2.$$

Then we can express $E$ and $p_z$ in function of the transverse energy $E_T$ and the rapidity $\eta$,

$$\begin{align}
E&=E_T\cosh\eta\\
p_z&=E_T\sinh\eta
\end{align}$$

The conservation of energy, of momentum along $z$, and of transverse momentum, in this order, reads:

$$\begin{align}
x_a \sqrt{S} + x_b\sqrt{S} &= E_{T1}\cosh\eta_1+E_{T2}\cosh\eta_2,\\
x_a \sqrt{S} - x_b\sqrt{S} &= E_{T1}\sinh\eta_1+E_{T2}\sinh\eta_2,\\
0 &= \vec{p}_{T1}+\vec{p}_{T2}.
\end{align}$$

and therefore the two final particles have the same transverse energy $E_T$, and we get the super classic formula,

$$\begin{align}
x_a &= \frac{E_T}{2\sqrt{S}}\left(e^{\eta_1}+e^{\eta_2}\right),\\
x_b &= \frac{E_T}{2\sqrt{S}}\left(e^{-\eta_1}-e^{-\eta_2}\right).
\end{align}$$

As you can see, the value of $x_a$ and $x_b$ is fixed by the kinematics. This is not just an academic exercise, as this is the kinematic of the Drell-Yann process, which is very useful, and of 2-jet events. The answer to your question is then obtained by looking how $\sqrt{x_ax_bS}$ varies with $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$. The distribution of $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ depends on the process of course but assuming uniform distributions already give an idea.

Further notes: for a $2\to 3$ event, the kinematic constraint loosen a bit, and $x_a$ and $x_b$ are allowed to vary within a range. I am talking about an inclusive cross section here of course, where one of the particle is integrated away. For an exclusive cross section, $x_a$ and $x_b$ are also fixed by the kinematic. The same analysis as above gives the values:

$$\begin{aligned}
x_a&=\sum_i \frac{E_{Ti}}{2\sqrt{S}}e^{\eta_i},\\
x_b&=\sum_i \frac{E_{Ti}}{2\sqrt{S}}e^{-\eta_i},
\end{aligned}$$

a formula which is valid for any number of final particles (the sum is over those).

Answer (score 0):

This is a general question which can only be asked for specific interaction, and this is done using monte-carlo simulations  which use the parton distribution functions of the proton as far as they have been ascertained by experiments.

See for example [this program](http://cds.cern.ch/record/1955754/files/arXiv:1410.4412.pdf):

> HERAFitter
>   is an open-source package that pro-
>   vides a framework for the determination of the parton distri-
>   bution functions (PDFs) of the proton and for many differ-
>   ent kinds of analyses in Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD).
>   It encodes results from a wide range of experimental measurements  in  lepton-proton  deep  inelastic  scattering  and
>   proton-proton (proton-antiproton) collisions at hadron colliders. These are complemented with a variety of theoretical
>   options for calculating PDF-dependent cross section predictions  corresponding  to  the  measurements.  The  framework
>   covers a large number of the existing methods and schemes
>   used for PDF determination.

Once one has the PDFs one can simulate the center of mass scattering according to the probabilities of interaction and the possible fourvectors, in a monte carlo simulation. This will give the maximum possible energies of parton parton collisions.The mean collision energy will depend on the particular interaction, as [pdf's are a function of x and  Q ,](http://cds.cern.ch/record/683851/files/phys-99-008.pdf) so it is not a simple number derivable from the energy of the beams.

See this [talk.](https://gsalam.web.cern.ch/gsalam/repository/talks/2009-Bautzen-lecture2.pdf)